# Delphi IXMLNode FindNode not working with namespace

Tags: xml, delphi, namespaces

this is a short example of my code, but good to understand my problem.

I have a xml file like this one:

```
<root xmlns:h="http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/">
  <h:data>
   <first>one</first>
   <second>two</second>
  </h:data>
</root>
```

This is my code in delphi:

```
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
xnode: IXMLNode;
Doc: TXMLDocument;
FileName : String;
begin
    XMLFileName := 'D:\doc.xml';
     Doc := TXMLDocument.Create(Application);

    Doc.LoadFromFile(XMLFileName);
    Doc.Active := true;
    // not working xnode is nil
    xnode := Doc.DocumentElement.ChildNodes.FindNode('data');

    //this also doesn't work, xnode is also nil

    xnode := Doc.DocumentElement.ChildNodes.FindNode('h:data');
    Doc.Free;
end;
```

With this xml file works fine, but unfortunally I have a namespace that I can not remove:

```
<root xmlns:h="http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/">
  <data>
   <first>one</first>
   <second>two</second>
  </data>
</root>
```

I am working with a complex xml file and I need that "FindNode" works with NameSpace.

Thanks in advance !

Answer (score 3):

You need to use the namespace overload:

```
xnode := Doc.DocumentElement.ChildNodes.FindNode('h:data', 'http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/');
```

This will return the node you are looking for.

If you want to search through all of the attributes in the root and read the namespaces then you can do this:

```
type
  TNamespaceAttribute = record
    namespace: string;
    namespaceurl: string;
  end;

var
  attrlist: array of TNamespaceAttribute;
  cntr: Integer;
begin
  // This will read in the list of namespaces
  for cntr := 0 to Doc.DocumentElement.AttributeNodes.Count - 1 do
  begin
    if Doc.DocumentElement.AttributeNodes[cntr].Prefix = 'xmlns' then
    begin
      // Don't like doing this but it gets the idea across
      SetLength(attrlist, Length(attrlist)+1);
      attrlist[High(attrlist)].namespace := Doc.DocumentElement.AttributeNodes[cntr].LocalName;
      attrlist[High(attrlist)].namespaceUrl := Doc.DocumentElement.AttributeNodes[cntr].Text;
    end;
  end;

  // You can iterate through them like this to get all of the instances
  // of the data node, regardless of the namespace 
  for cntr := Low(attrlist) to High(attrlist) do
  begin
    xnode := Doc.DocumentElement.ChildNodes.FindNode(attrlist[cntr].namespace+':data', attrlist[cntr].namespaceurl);
    // Do something here
  end;
end;
```

Comment: Hi Graymatter, it works ! But now my doubt is the following. I know that parent node is in this case root, but how can I get the namespace "h" and the url "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/".

Comment: @user1727336 You will need to know what your namespaces are. If you don't know them then you can retrieve a list of namespaces by accessing the attributes on the root but then you will need to scan the entire xml file to see which ones are being used and where. Are you always looking to retrieve the node on the root called data, irrespective of the namespaces?